# Box2D Qt wrong collisions

Tags: box2d, qt

I am working on a simple Box2D game (with Qt), but my objects don't collide correctly:

[image]

As you can see on the picture, objects try to go through each other and slide over.

My b2World:

```
b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -9.8f);
world = new b2World(gravity);
```

How I add objects:

```
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
if (dynamic) bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.Set(centerX, centerY);
body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

b2PolygonShape box;
box.SetAsBox(width/2, height/2);

b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.shape = &box;
fixtureDef.density = 1;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.5;
fixtureDef.restitution = 0.2;
body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
```

for drawing, ppm - pixel per meter, scene - QGraphicsScene, rect - QGraphicsRectItem:

```
rect = scene->addRect(getRect(centerX*ppm, centerY*ppm, width*ppm, height*ppm));
```

Function to get QRectF (it takes left and top coordinates, not center):

```
QRectF GRect::getRect(float32 centerX, float32 centerY, float32 W, float32 H)
{
    return QRectF(centerX - W/2, centerY - H/2, W, H);
}
```

And how I draw every object:

```
b2Vec2 position = body->GetPosition();
rect->setRect(getRect(position.x*_ppm, position.y*_ppm, _width*_ppm, _height*_ppm));
rect->setRotation(body->GetAngle());
```

I tried to play with density, friction and restitution values, but it has no effect. Help.
PS. Sory for bad English, I am from Russia

Comment: What is the frame rate you get with the game and could you also show code for the way you call box2d world step. It looks like the step value might be to big. Do you use fixed time-step: http://blog.allanbishop.com/box-2d-2-1a-tutorial-part-10-fixed-time-step/

Comment: every 16 msec I call `world->Step(1.0f/60.0f, 8, 3);` and it looks very smooth